# Parsing markdown files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got 2 markdown files in a certain location, contents are

```
---
title: test markdown file 1
date: 2020/02/11
---
This is a short one line paragraph.
```

```
---
title: test markdown file 2
date: 2020/02/12
---
This is a short 2 line paragraph.
```

i want to parse them and below is the code however i get only 1 value as output below,
OUTPUT
{'title': 'test markdown file 2', 'date': '2020/02/12'}
This is a short 2 line paragraph.

how can i get the contents of the first markdown file as well?

```
 import frontmatter,os
    path = 'C:/input/'
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
      print(entry.path)
      post = frontmatter.load(entry)

    print(post.metadata)
    print(post.content)
```

Comment: your `print(post.metadata)` etc statements are outside the `for` loop. you need to indent them one level more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the two posts in the for loop to the same variable and then **after the for loop** you print your variable values...

If you put the print commands inside the for loop, you get your desired outcome. ;)

```
import frontmatter,os
path = 'C:/input/'
for entry in os.scandir(path):
  print(entry.path)
  post = frontmatter.load(entry)
  print(post.metadata)
  print(post.content)
```

Comment: Thanks BUFU works it was a such a silly mistake i made sorry for the trouble and thanks for your quick assistance much appreciated :-)

Comment: No problem at all. Would you mind marking the answer as correct so the question will not linger as "unsolved"? =)
(I think SO would appreciate it.)